# TYPO3 $query->in('valOne,valTwo,valThree', $arrayTwo)

Tags: sql, typo3

I have a query in my repository which gets all product by categories and contentTypes.
I am looking for a query like this:

```
 $query = $this->createQuery();
    $constraint = $query->in('category', $categories);

    if (!empty($contentType)) {

        $results = $query->matching(
            $query->logicalAnd(
                $constraint, $query->in('contentType', $contentType)
            )
        )
        ->setLimit((int)$limit)
        ->setOffset((int)$offset)
        ->execute()
        ->toArray();
```

It works well if 'containType' contains just a single id as string, e.g '261'.
But if it is a string with multiple id's it looks like '261,284,291' and the query does not work longer.

I hope you got all information. Let me know if not :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `GeneralUtility::trimExplode()` or in your case probably more specific `GeneralUtility::intExplode()` to turn the `$contentType` CSV value into an array of values suitable for `QueryInterface::in()`.

Comment: Well  `$contentType` is already an array.
The 'contentType' is the property (VARCHAR) of my product-Entity and that is what i need to compare against `$contentType`

Comment: That's not what you wrote in your OP however. If `$contentType` already is an array, then there's actually nothing to do. Did you mix this up with `contains()`?

Comment: `$query->contains('contentType', $contentType)` does not work.
the column 'contentType' is a Varchar with comma-separated id's. 

An error appears "#1327065745: Unsupported or non-existing property name "contentType" used in relation matching."

"contentType" is an extended sys_category.

Comment: Sorry, I have no idea how your data structure, models and configuration looks like. Unless you add way more details about this to your OP, I can barely help here.